# When you extend an abstract class which implements an interface does it make the class a type of interface and abstract?

Tags: java

I'm currently preparing for my scjp exam. I know that *IS-A* means extends an *HAS-A* means to have an instance of another object. But what if you extend an abstract class which implements another interface, does it make the class a type of interface and abstract as well?

```
interface Animal{
    void eat();
    void sleep();
}
 abstract class Duck implements Animal{
    public void eat(){}
    public void sleep(){}
 }
 class Animals extends Duck{
     //dosomething...
 }
```

class Animals IS-A(N) Animal and IS-A Duck

or

class Animals IS-A(N) Animal

or

class Animals IS-A Duck

Comment: a class can only be abstract if it's declared explicitly so.

Comment: The example makes little sense. `Duck` is abstract but has no abstract methods and `Animals extends Duck` is not something we could logically expect. However, the first answer is the right one.

Comment: Not to mention that `Animal` isn't used anywhere.

Comment: Maybe `Animal -> Bird -> Duck` would make more sense as an example.

Comment: Define 'type of interface and abstract'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sub-class would be a type of that interface. However, whether the sub-class would be abstract or not depends on whether you define it to be abstract or not.

In your example (which uses class names that make no sense), the sub-class is not abstract, which means it would have to implement all the abstract methods of its abstract super-class and all the methods of the interface not already implemented by the abstract super-class.

Comment: sorry.. forgot to implement the animal interface, but you got the question anyway thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of Object-Oriented design, both `implements SomeInterface` and `extends SomeClass` create an IS-A relationship. In both cases you create a subtype of the interface of class.

What this does *not* mean, however, is that now the subclass is also an interface or that it is also abstract. A type can only be an interface if it is declared with the keyword `interface` and it can only be an abstract class if it is declared with both the keyword `abstract` and the keyword `class`.

In your example, class Animals is both a Duck and an Animal. But it is not an interface or an abstract class.

By the way, choosing to call your class "Animals" may indicate that you're missing something about the relation. A subtype is always *more specific* than the type it extends. So maybe if you called it "Mallard" it would represent the relationship more accurately: A Mallard is a specific kind of Duck and also a specific kind of Animal. And it is a specific kind of Animal because a Duck is a specific kind of Animal.